# Docker Local Machine

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-image

Was wondering whether it's possible to use docker to provision a local machine. I have tried researching this but I can't seem to find any conclusive answers.

For example I have a low powered Ubuntu server. I want to install Jenkins on it. Does Jenkins need to run inside a virtual machine on my server, can I run it directly on the server inside a docker container?

Comment: Why the down vote? Please can you give constructive criticism so that I can improve my question.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I suspect it was because many of these questions could be answered with minimal research.  There isn't a specific technical question here, and no evidence that you have tried something on your own.

Comment: @larsks... thank you. I had originally written that I had researched using both Google and pluralsight to little avail. I edited the house because I felt that it was not relevant. I can't seem to find an answer to this. If it does really require minimal research. Then I feel it should be an easy question to answer. Yet nobody has been able to answer. It is all the same question rephrased several times for clarity.

Comment: @larsks I took in your comments on board and amended the wording of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get hold of Dan Wahlin (http://codewithdan.com/) who kindly answered my question on posted on the PluralSight course discussion.

The answer is yes it can be done, but only if using Linux or Windows Server 2016 (at present).